# How to run JUnit Test in maven if the test are not in test dir but in main dir and the classname are not having keywords like .*Test.*

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, junit

Here is the back ground.

I was working on a project which was using ant build. When we use to create a new Class, we use to write the junit test in same class as ant supported it.The Class Name doesn't have 'Test' naming convention.  There are more then 800 Junit tests.

Now we need to move to Maven build structure. Problem is that maven only runs junit where the class name has naming convention 'Test'.

How do i run the junit test which are in in src/main/java/* ?

Also, Is there a  way where i can pull all methods that has '@Test' annotations?

Please let me know if you need any further info.

Comment: I would consider moving files having `@Test` annotation to your test folder by applying `grep` and `'your-vcs' mv` command.

Comment: No other solution:(. I cann't move the file in src/test/java as they are the normal java classes.

Answer (score 2):

Just because you used to do it like that with Ant, doesn't make it right to keep using it now. Now that you've moved to Maven, you must comply with its way of doing things and follow its conventions. One of them is to keep your production code separate from your tests. A mixture does not make sense, as you are in fact littering your code with useless (for clients of your code) methods. While you can keep doing this and find workarounds, this is not the high-standard route to choose.

What you really need to do as a next step is schedule some refactoring time and carry out the following tasks:

- Create `src/test/java` (and respectively -- `src/test/resources`).
- Create a `*Test` class for each class that contains `@Test` annotated methods and place them under `src/test/java`.
- Move those methods to the respective new classes.
- Move all your resources that are only used by tests to your `src/test/resources` directory.

Comment: "you must comply with it's way of doing things" -- *should* comply.

Comment: Very well. Re-phrased. Frankly, I feel you "must".

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the configuration of the [Surefire plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/), which runs the tests. I have not tested it, but you can try this configuration:

```
<build>
  <testSourceDirectory>src/main/java</testSourceDirectory>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.16</version>
      <configuration>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.java</include>
        </includes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: No. Its not working.
This is what i see on console:
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) @ MavenDemo ---
[INFO] No tests to run.


I have created a sample test.

  @Test
    public void testSysmteOut(){
    org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(9,9);
    }

Name of Class:MakeCasesTest.java

Its in src/main/java/

Comment: The example was incorrect. The testSourceDirectory node must be a child of build instead of configuration. The current example is correct and has been tested.

Comment: While the above might work, I strongly advise to not use it. This will not solve the problem, but only make it worse.

Answer (score 0):

I assume since you are using ant, you have a test suite?  If so, the easiest way is to change the configuration to use the given test suite:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.4</version>
  <configuration>
    <includes>
      <include>AllTest.class</include>
    </includes>
  </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

However, I'm not sure if it will look in the src folder too so you may have to move the test suite to the test directory.

As for pulling all methods that have the @Test annotation (I assume without a suite?) you will have to do that yourself if you aren't following the sure-fire test class naming conventions.  It isn't too hard to make your own test runner implementation that searches through all your classes in your class path or a sub-folder and finds all classes that meet your criteria and pass that to Junit to run.

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't run the test in src/main/java dir

Comment: @PankajDev If you can't move the class, why not create a new test suite in the test directory that just invokes the one in main?

Comment: I m not really getting what u mean by test suite here. Can u give me example.

Comment: TestSuites are ways to group multiple test classes together so run them all.  See JUnit's tutorial on their wiki: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Aggregating-tests-in-suites  How are you running your 800 tests currently?

Comment: I m not using testsuite. In ants build,for target 'test', I have specifed the src and it runs all junit test.

Comment: Wow, this worked. Thanks a lot guys. I can run test from src/main/java/

`    <build>  
      <plugins>  
       <plugin>  
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>  
        <configuration>  
         <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</testSourceDirectory>  
         <testClassesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/</testClassesDirectory>  
        </configuration>  
       </plugin>  
      </plugins>  
     </build>  
  
    Results :
    
    Tests run: 20, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

`

Comment: Yeah, well... while this might work, it's really not a good idea to be doing it that way. Check my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse, you can still execute it as Junit test.

In fact, if your "test classes" didn't put in the test folder, it means that you do not intend to run them as "test" at the maven build action.